# Rails: redirect to a specific tab

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have the following tabs:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="prodTabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#other"  data-toggle="tab">Other search</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="search">

    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="other">
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following javascript:

```
<script>
$('#tabs').on('click','.tablink,#prodTabs a',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");

    if (typeof url !== "undefined") {
        var pane = $(this), href = this.hash;

        // ajax load from data-url
        $(href).load(url,function(result){
            pane.tab('show');
        });
    } else {
        $(this).tab('show');
    }
});
</script>

<script>
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    initialize();
});
</script>
```

The tab named `other` contains a search form and a map, once the form is submitted I get redirected to a new page. From this new page I would like to be able to go back to the `other` tab, but I would like to view the same exact content it had when the form was submitted.

Any ideas how I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The browser back button does this. You can also add a button to go back:

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
  function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pablo! I tried this out ,and although this goes back to the correct path it does not go back to the correct tab. It goes back to the first tab which is the active one. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure. Does the browser back button do the same? I'm using it and it goes back to the last open tab.

Comment: Yes, it does the same exact thing. It redirects me to the previous page but to the active tab and not the to the tab that was previously open.